# Sitecore: override ChnagePassword class

Tags: sitecore9

Not able to find dll to override Sitecore.Shell.Applications.Security.ChangePassword.ChangePasswordPage class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might be looking for [Sitecore.Client.dll](https://sitecore.myget.org/feed/sc-packages/package/nuget/Sitecore.Client), the naming convention `shell = client`